# Spring Rest Web Request Scope

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, rest

I'm in the process of writing a Spring REST type interface to a database that will retrieve user specific results for various resources.

To hold the user I have a spring @Component annotated bean called CurrentUser as a temporary measure.

```
@Component
public class CurrentUser {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;    

    private String userId;
    private String email;
    private String notes;

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) throws ApiException {  
        User user = userDAO.getUser(userId) // Database call to 
        if (!user.isValid()) {
            throw ApiException(...)     // The exception would crash back to the user as a error in the response
        }       

        // Valud user so set these aspects. 
        this.userId = user.userId;      
        this.email = user.email;
    }
}
```

This object is initialised in a Spring Interceptor on each call to any method in the API using the following interceptor.

```
public class AuthenticationInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private CurrentUser user; 

    @Autowired
    private RequestParameters requestParameters;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws ApiException {
        user.setUserId(StringUtils.defaultString(request.getParameter("userId"), "defaultUser"));
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is only a place-holder to identify the users until proper authentication can be added.

I'm relatively new to Spring, and the reason for this post 
is to increase my understanding of the thread safety aspects of Spring in situations like this

I've recently discovered that Spring is not automatically thread safe, I may need to give more consideration to the scopes.

What I want to understand is the following:

1. For the above setup, is there any danger that 1000s of simultaneous requests, would potentially interfere and overwrite each other? 
   e.g. A request for one user would potentially be overwritten with a different user from a separate http request, causing the requestor to receive the wrong data.
2. What would be the best approach to solving this. (Even though it will be replaced, I have other objects instantiated in similar ways)
   Options I'm looking at (if this is an issue), is setting prototype scope, or attaching to the request / session directly rather than allowing them their own autowired object.

Any information anyone could give me would be much appreciated, as I'm a fan of getting it right(er) to start with, than dealing with bad assumptions later on.

Comment: We even had this doubt and had rigorous bulk testing and found that the spring by default doesnot handle request based data. So either have Transactional based configuration enabled in the project and in the service layers. 

Also you can configure the beans in the Request scope which ideally is having a similar effect of putting a synchronized block inside methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer 1: Yes, and you don't need 1000 requests to get into trouble. 2 requests in parallel are enough.

Answer 2:
The main problem here is one of scoping:

Default scope of Spring managed beans is Singleton. That means that only one instance of your CurrentUser exists per Application.

That is obviously not what you want. (Since you have a severe security issue here, with only one CurrentUser instance per application).

Simple Answer:

I would probably use Spring Security ;-)

Even Simpler Answer:

If that is not an option:

- Use a Filter instead of a HandlerInterceptor (more direct control over clean up)
- Create a Thread Local to store the user (and use a finally in the Filter to clean it up) and set it in the Filter
- Create a request scoped Service (use @ScopedProxy, to be able to wire it into Singletons), that accesses the ThreadLocal as a UserService (you will need an interface to make it work easily)
- Autowire this UserService where you need it

Since by specification each request in a Servlet environment is bound to a thread, and thread locals are inherently thread-safe, you are completely thread safe and it will scale well. The overhead of the scoped proxy is minimal.

(This is only one option, other options could make use of the request scope explicitly or use aspects in a slightly more elegant manner. However, it is a rather simple approach and gets the job done. For more complex needs I would seriously  recommend looking into Spring Security).

Comment: Just what I was looking for. The actual security implementation is still in flux as it needs to hook up to an SSO provider. (I'm still getting my head around some of that). This example was one of a few spring beans in the project that could run into the issues so beyond the security itself this answer fits. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You ca use parameter resolver feature of spring mvc without making it a bean.
to do that implement the interface HandlerMethodArgumentResolver and register that into the container. And then your handler method can have a argument of type current user

```
import org.springframework.core.MethodParameter;
import org.springframework.web.bind.support.WebDataBinderFactory;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolver;
import org.springframework.web.method.support.ModelAndViewContainer;

public class CurrentUserArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver{

@Override
public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
    if (parameter.getParameterType().equals(CurrentUser.class)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest,
        WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
    if (supportsParameter(parameter)) {
        String userId = (String) webRequest.getAttribute("userId", NativeWebRequest.SCOPE_REQUEST);
        return new CurrentUser(userId);
    }
    return null;
}

public class CurrentUser{

    public CurrentUser(String userId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
}
```

After this you can have handler method of stype

```
@RequestMapping
public String handler(CurrentUser user){
....
}
```